# Crash with .cxx_destruct after (?) XCTestCase run

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, exc-bad-access, xctest

I just added a new TestCase to a library and now my tests are suddenly crashing with a strange stack trace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2e4275, 0x007a80b2 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 14, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x202989c2)


*   frame #0: 0x007a80b2 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 14
    frame #1: 0x05fc88ac CoreData`-[_CDSnapshot dealloc] + 92
    frame #2: 0x05fc6fed CoreData`-[_CDSnapshot release] + 77
    frame #3: 0x05fd1c34 CoreData`-[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _clearRawPropertiesWithHint:] + 356
    frame #4: 0x05fd1a3b CoreData`-[NSFaultHandler turnObject:intoFaultWithContext:] + 411
    frame #5: 0x06006d1b CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _disposeObjects:count:notifyParent:] + 395
    frame #6: 0x06006392 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _dispose:] + 578
    frame #7: 0x06005e5f CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext _dealloc__] + 319
    frame #8: 0x06005cf6 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext dealloc] + 70
    frame #9: 0x05fc8ced CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext release] + 77
    frame #10: 0x007a8e97 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release + 71
    frame #11: 0x007a8e3e libobjc.A.dylib`objc_storeStrong + 39
    frame #12: 0x02e7a58d MyLibTests`-[M2BCoreDataManager .cxx_destruct](self=0x0287c0d0, _cmd=0x007ae6b7) + 221 at M2BCoreDataManager.m:19
    frame #13: 0x007972d4 libobjc.A.dylib`object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 128
    frame #14: 0x0079724f libobjc.A.dylib`object_cxxDestruct + 20
    frame #15: 0x007a227a libobjc.A.dylib`objc_destructInstance + 48
    frame #16: 0x007a22ab libobjc.A.dylib`object_dispose + 20
    frame #17: 0x007a9692 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 268
    frame #18: 0x007a8e81 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release + 49
    frame #19: 0x007a9ce7 libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 537
    frame #20: 0x20103dbe XCTest`-[XCTestCase performTest:] + 178
    frame #21: 0x20104c48 XCTest`-[XCTest run] + 82
    frame #22: 0x201033e8 XCTest`-[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 139
    frame #23: 0x20104c48 XCTest`-[XCTest run] + 82
    frame #24: 0x201033e8 XCTest`-[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 139
    frame #25: 0x20104c48 XCTest`-[XCTest run] + 82
    frame #26: 0x201033e8 XCTest`-[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 139
    frame #27: 0x20104c48 XCTest`-[XCTest run] + 82
    frame #28: 0x201066ba XCTest`+[XCTestProbe runTests:] + 183
    frame #29: 0x007aa743 libobjc.A.dylib`+[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    frame #30: 0x0000233e xctest`___lldb_unnamed_function9$$xctest + 195
    frame #31: 0x00002590 xctest`___lldb_unnamed_function11$$xctest + 246
    frame #32: 0x00002671 xctest`___lldb_unnamed_function12$$xctest + 52
    frame #33: 0x00002007 xctest`___lldb_unnamed_function2$$xctest + 45
```

The only line that is related to my code is frame #12.

The M2BCoreDataManager is the superclass of a simple helper class I use in all my tests cases to set up the CoreData stack.

Before making the change I had 4 different classes testing parsing of JSON to my CoreData model objects. Each of those creates an instance of the M2BCoreDataManager subclass to set up the CoreDataStack with the library's CoreData model file and a special store location for the test cases.

All I did before the crash happened is add a 5th test cases for another model class and copy over (and slightly modify) one of the other test cases.
I did one more thing: I deleted the Derived Data folder, as Xcode was using an old version of the CoreData model for the tests and added the model file to the test target. Not sure whether this has anything to do with it.

I think the crash is related to the test cases `tearDown` as I do get test failures from the new test, so the test seems to be run, but it still crashes.

The crash sounds as if it is related to an overrelease, so I tried enabling NSZombie in the libraries run scheme configuration, but I'm not sure whether that works when running the test. At least it didn't change anything. I have no clue what else to try or what the cause of the problem could be.

Each of my Core Data related tests cases looks like this:

```
@interface GREmailJSONInitialization : XCTestCase

@property (strong) GRCoreDataModelTestsHelper *coreDataHelper;

@end

@implementation GREmailJSONInitialization

- (void)setUp
{
    self.coreDataHelper = [[GRCoreDataModelTestsHelper alloc] initWithTestStoreName:@"NoteInitializationTest"];

    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.

    NSError *cleanUpError = nil;
    BOOL cleanUp = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:self.coreDataHelper.testStoreURL error:&cleanUpError];
    if (!cleanUp)
    {
        XCTFail(@"Could not clean up temporary store due to error: %@", cleanUpError);
    }
    self.coreDataHelper = nil;

    [super tearDown];
}
```

`GRCoreDataModelTestHelper` is the mentioned subclass of M2BCoreDataManager. All it does is specify a model URL and a store URL to use when setting up the CoreData stack.

All I do is create the `GRCoreDataModelTestHelper` on setup and remove the PersistentStore file on tearDown, also removing the `GRCoreDataModelTestHelper` by setting the property to nil. I set a break-point there and the `self.coreDataHelper = nil;` does not cause the crash, it is successfully executed.

Any ideas what the reason could be or pointers what else to try to track down the problem?

EDIT: So the problem went away by itself, but I have no clue what happened or what I changed...

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am struggling with exactly the same crash, also in the tests. After the tests. I was able to force the error by calling reset on the context before completing the test.

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't. As mentioned in the edit it went away after some time, but I didn't even know what I changed. :(

Comment: Ok for me it was a retainedValue which was not released from a using selector on a managed object. Turned it into an unretainedValue and everything was fine. Hope it helps other people out there ;-)